# Why does outlook 2013, after initial setup, always fail to connect to an Exchange server/always ask for a password?

Tags: exchange

After installing Outlook 2013 configuring it to connect to an exchange server (details about which, e.g., version, etc., I do not know how to provide) was stressful and the user used outlook without issue for a session. The next time outlook is started this error (Re. subject) occurs. The answer to this question solves the issue, or explains why it is happening (i.e., no one could provide a solution).

[image]

Full size image: [http://i.imgur.com/H2bVlyJ.png](https://i.imgur.com/H2bVlyJ.png)

EDIT 5/18: To add more detail, a) after outlook 2013 was installed and configured (through the menu it prompts you with, add an account) it connected and was fine. It is only after outlook is closed and re-opened that it will not connect again to the server. This problem has been mentioned elsewhere, e.g., http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/62832.aspx.

Comment: Is 'Remember my credentials' being clicked?

Comment: Yes. Even so, it will not connect w/ the given username and password.

Comment: Is this an on-premise Exchange server or Office 365?

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since you posted this question but eventually it helps someone other who gets here..

I'll just explain what worked in our environment:

1) Make sure you have installed Outlook 2010 SP2 or Outlook 2013

2) When adding your Outlook Account you need to do/check following:

-Leave **Exchange-Caching Mode** **Enabled** (You can disable it later)

-Before clicking "Finish" go to "**Advanced Settings**" and under "**Security**" check if you have enabled to encrypt data betweend Outlook and Exchange (Checkbox), do not tick to ask everytime and change **Network Security at Logon** to **NTLM** authentication. The NTLM setting also applies to Exchange Anywhere, but this should be default there. If you forget this part, you can't change it afterwards, it always discards your changes after you apply them.

3) When starting Outlook you may have to enter account settings for the first time. (Don't forget ticking "Save Credentials")

4) Same goes for every additional Account you add to your Outlook.

Short Explanation: If you have more than one Account in your Outlook, Windows somehow is not able to tell which Account needs whose authentication. By enabling Caching-Mode and changing Settings to NTLM it should add an Entry in your **Credential Manager** for each additional account you add to your Outlook. (If you are using a proxy server you may have to disable this one if the stepas above didn't work) If this works correctly, it should not ask for your password again each time you start outlook.
If the entry has been succefully made, you need to remove the login information for your webmail (Otherwise you will be having trouble configuring your Out-of-office messages)

Sorry if some of the setting-names do not exactly match the correct ones, i'm using outlook in another language.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

According to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH83z.png) this is an unresolved bug with Outlook 2013.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH83z.png) http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/62832.aspx

To solve this issue I checked/uncheck two boxes as shown in these pictures: 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting the same kind of Error for a long Period of time. After trying several and probably most of the Answers provided on different forums I messed around with the settings myself.

Let me first describe my configuration/usage of exchange:
I´m a student and have gotten a first.lastname@student.fhnw.ch address. I check my mails often closing and starting Outlook and it became really frustrating.

When I looked through the advanced settings outlook made up by itself there was one setting I could not understand why it would be like this.

Go to your profile settings in outlook:
-> select your faulty exchange config -> cklick change -> advanced settings
-> security (make sure establish connection over http is checked)
-> click on exchange proxy settings: Here you find two settings saying to use http instead of tcp/ip when checked. Check both boxes for slower and faster internet connections.

Since I dont know a lot about Networking I can only make a guess why this is.
When I want to log into Outlook Webmail I first have to log into the user management system of my university. After this I am redirected to Webmail. So my conclusion is that the login system of my university comes between Outlook and Webmail and it really doesnt like the use of tcp/ip.
But again it´s a wild guess on a working solution.

I hope it helps you out.

Regards